# SQLite and LibreBase

Tags: sqlite

I have an SQLite database and a LibreBase interface, my interface in LibreBase will not work because it says "Database does not support relations" and "Database does not support FULL or LEFT Joins". I have tried both ODBC and JDBC Drivers for SQLite3 in both LibreBase and Open Office and also enabled the FKey's. The interface worked, with some adjustments, in both Postgres and HSQL. Pretty sure SQLite3 supports all these functions; any ideas as to what is going wrong?

Comment: Might have to do this in the SQLite Db: `PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;` (See http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html)

Comment: I ensured they were turned on in the Database and I set the ODBC and JDBC drivers to use the FKey constraints.

Comment: Did some more work on this with the help of the Ask LibreOffice group. Rebuilding the table with the Foreign Keys in DB Browser with no change in the behavior.